# Is it possible to add query on a JSON based on URL provided by users?

Tags: php, json

My question is,
is it possible to manipulate JSON object based on the URL that the users' provided?

For instance,
let say I have a simple JSON : `local/color_rgbval/colors`

```
[
{
    color: "red",
    value: "#f00"
},
{
    color: "green",
    value: "#0f0"
},
{
    color: "blue",
    value: "#00f"
},
{
    color: "cyan",
    value: "#0ff"
}
]
```

I want to fetch only the value of color green.
so the user will just type in `local/color_rgbval/colors?=green` *(something like that)*

Comment: JSON is just a data format. You need a programming language. PHP can do it. Writing the whole thing is too broad of a problem for Stackoverflow though. You need to do your research, make an effort and (possibly) come back with a more specific problem.

Comment: @Quentin so does it mean JSON will just simple display all the data in my *let say* database and in my mobile app *let say* iOS, there I can manipulate data from JSON? is my understanding now correct?

Comment: JSON will contain whatever data you put in it. If you put all the data in your database in it then it will contain all the data in your database. If you sent it to an app running under iOS and had written that app to manipulate that data, then it could manipulate that data.

Answer (score 0):

**ALL THIS COULD BE DONT BY JAVASCRIPT**

1st : Use URL fragments ie. #
URL would look like  *www.webstie.com#**school*** *www.webstie.com#**college***

That way URL changing would not cause a refresh or redirect,

2nd.  Add a **hashchange** event like

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(e){ 
   var currentURL = window.location.hash; // will give school ,college
   updateJson(currentURL )   .. write logic to update THE jsoN
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking past the invalid JSON snippet you've posted --

You could do it this way;

Your set of JSON data:

```
$rawJson = '[
{
    "color": "red",
    "value": "#f00"
},
{
    "color": "green",
    "value": "#0f0"
},
{
    "color": "blue",
    "value": "#00f"
},
{
    "color": "cyan",
    "value": "#0ff"
}
]';
```

Next, let's parse this data and create an array we could more easily search:

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($rawJson, true);
```

Lastly, lets search for the given input, in this case: `green`:

```
$searchFor = 'green';
$keyFound  = array_search($searchFor, array_column($jsonArray, 'color'));

if ($keyFound) {
    // answer
    $result = $jsonArray[$keyFound];

    var_dump($result);
}
```

Breaking this down further; `array_column($jsonArray, 'color')` will create an array of just the colors in the given array. Then using `array_search` we will search for the given color and return the index/key of the position we found the input color.

If the key is found, the `$jsonArray[$keyFound]` would give us the correct answer.